# Mistake when calculating the polar form of $-3\mathrm{i}$

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

Given the complex number $x+y\mathrm{i} = -3\mathrm{i}$, I want to calculate the polar form $r\mathrm{e}^{\varphi\mathrm{i}}$ using this definition for $\varphi$:

$\varphi = \begin{cases}
\arctan(\frac y x) &\text{if } x > 0, \\
\arctan(\frac y x) + \pi &\text{if } x < 0 \text{ and } y \ge 0, \\
\arctan(\frac y x) - \pi &\text{if } x < 0 \text{ and } y < 0, \\
+\frac{\pi}{2} &\text{if } x = 0 \text{ and } y > 0, \\
-\frac{\pi}{2} &\text{if } x = 0 \text{ and } y < 0.
\end{cases}$

so, if I understand correctly, since $x=0$ and $y = -3 < 0$, $\varphi$ should be $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ in this case, yielding

$3\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{i}}$

but instead, the correct answer seems to be

$3\mathrm{e}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}\mathrm{i}}$.

I cannot see where I made the mistake and would be happy if you could help me with showing why exactly (and where) I am wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yo did not make any mistake: $$3\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{i}}=
3\mathrm{e}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}\mathrm{i}}.$$The usual form is the second one, though.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only a matter of definition for the principal argument.

It can be

- $[0,2\pi)$

or

- $[-\pi,\pi)$

Thus both the polar form represent the same complex number $-3i$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, if I understand correctly, it doesn't matter whether I write $3\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$ or $3\mathrm{e}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}$ assuming that it is not stated whether $\varphi \in [0, 2\pi)$ or $\varphi \in [-\pi, \pi]$?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow they represent the same complex number, when we need to define a unique value we need to refer to the principal argument $\phi$ which definition is not unique, but od course $\phi +2k\pi$ are ok to represent the same complex number.

Comment: Alright, thank you, that made it clear for me.